# Function never uses updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, react-navigation

In the sample component below, `myFunc`'s `state1` is never updated while the `console.log` in the `useEffect` outputs the updated state correctly. What could be the reason for this?

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state1);
  }, [state1]);
  
  const myFunc(() => {
    const newState1 = getNewState1();
    console.log(state1);  // never outputs updated state, even when myFunc is called multiple times
    if (state1 !== newState1) {
      console.log('updated state');
      setState1(newState1); 
    }
  });
}
```

Obviously, my real component is much more complicated, but the only time `setState1` is called is in `myFunc` which is confirmed by the `useEffect`.

Edit:

```
const TestComponent2 = () => {
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      myFunc();
    }),
  );
};
```

I am trying to call `myFunc` when `TextComponent2` is focused/loaded. I realize that `useEffect` with no dependencies may be the best option here. Thanks!

Comment: What does `getState1()` do? Ideally you'd move your conditional statement into a `useEffect`.

Comment: I meant for the function to get a new `state1` that may or may not be different from the previous `state`.

Comment: Where is myFunc called?

Comment: I just realized I'm calling the function in `useCallback`. Would that cause `state1` to remain the same?

Comment: Are you supplying state1 as a dependency to your `useCallback` function?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Please provide more context

Answer (score 1):

I was using `useCallback` with no relevant dependencies which most likely caused `state1` to be the same.